# Python3 Tkinter - Open .py file with button

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.4

I have multiple .py tkinter GUIs that I want to combine. I did not initially plan on combining them into one GUI, so I have many variables in common as well as global commands which makes putting each window in a function in order to combine it under one .py file difficult. So I was trying to see if I can get buttons to open the applications separately to get the same thing done. I have a menu with some buttons and it works, however if I close one window and return to the menu, I cannot "reimport" a .py file so I cannot go into a new window, close it and go back. Here's my code:

```
def newWindow():
    root.destroy()
    import newFile

button1 = tk.Button(root, command=newWindow)
button1.pack()
```

To make the issue more clear: Say I start off on the menu. I click a button to close the menu and open a new window with a separate program on it. I close that program which automatically reopens the menu. However, now when I open the program from the menu again, the menu closes, but the program will not reopen as it has already been imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright @drsom, this should work, where you `import py1` you should instead have `from py1 import func1` then `func1()` on the next line (obviously this means you will have to create `func1` and `func2` like I've done below), this for some reason will allow you to carry on forever, I don't know why plain importing won't. In addition to this you must add (after the function) `if __name__ == '__main__':` and `func2()` on the next line to run that function the first time and start the cycle.

a small example:

**py1:**

```
def func1():
    import tkinter as tk

    root1 = tk.Tk()

    def kill1():
        root1.destroy()
        from py2 import func2
        func2()

    button1 = tk.Button(root1, bg = 'green', text = 'hit to kill py1 and start py2', command = kill1)
    button1.pack()

    root1.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func1()
```

**py2:**

```
def func2():
    import tkinter as tk

    root2 = tk.Tk()

    def kill2():
        root2.destroy()
        from py1 import func1
        func1()

    button2 = tk.Button(root2, bg = 'red', text = 'hit to kill py2 and start py1', command = kill2)
    button2.pack()

    root2.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func2()
```

This should work, but may cause some issues if the code is meant to carry on after the original function. I'm not sure what else you wanted, but just ask :), hope this helps you.

Comment: This works great and it addresses the problem of 'reimpoting'. It is actually only importing once and running the function multiple times, which works great. Just to mention, I found a more personally acceptable solution using "import runpy", but since you address the original issue I will consider this the confirmed answer.